# Create documents with java

Tags: java, katalon-studio

I'm kinda new to java and trying to create files to test uploads with in Katalon Studio on debian 9.

My Class looks like:

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("/home/timo/Downloads/example.txt");
            BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            output.write("Hello World");
            output.close();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm calling it with:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
Application files = new Application();
```

I don't get an error but the file also ain't at the specified path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static main method is an entry point of a java program. It is not obvious where do you call it from. But typically, you should compile your application that contains your `Application` class using compiler, like this:

```
javac Application.java
```

and run it as a java application like

```
java Application
```

Or using your IDE.

Comment: Thank you, that lead me to the answer for solving my problem.
Needed to remove the class declaration and main function, cause they're not needed in katalon.

See this for more information: https://forum.katalon.com/t/java-scripting-in-katalon/8595/2